# Checking for a list within a list

Tags: java, arrays

The method's description is given below and that is the code I have so far. I'm programming an online zoo where a customer puts in an order for a bunch of animals and I need to tell the customer if I have the animals that he has requested. The animals in the inventory and the customer's request list are all arranged in descending order of retail value. So if the customer ordered two cheetahs, they would both appear side by side in the inventory and his list. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Also, I can't use any sorting algorithms, any counting algorithms or any Java feature really. It's a simple array manipulation project that I need to complete using for loops and conditionals.

```
         * Checks if a list of items is contained in the current list. If the list
         * of items has duplicates then the current list must have that many of the
         * item as well. (In other words, this method will return true if ALL of the
         * items in the parameter are contained in the current list. If anything is
         * missing, then the return value will be false.)
         * 
         * @param listToCheck
         *            list of items that may or may not be a subset of the current
         *            list
         * @return true if the parameter is a subset of the current list; false
         *         otherwise 

    public boolean checkAvailability(SortedListOfImmutables listToCheck) {
            int pos = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i<items.length; i++){ //items is the original array
                if(listToCheck.items[0].equals(items[i])){
                    pos = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            int availableCounter = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i<listToCheck.items.length; i++){
                if(listToCheck.items[i].equals(items[pos])){
                    pos++;
                    availableCounter++;
                }
                else
                    pos++;

            }
            if(availableCounter == listToCheck.items.length-1){
                 return true;
              }
return false; 
        }
```

Comment: can you post sample input and desired output ?

Comment: @Atul Nar items [ alligator, armadillo, cheetah, cheetah, eagle, elephant, gecko, lion ] 
listToCheck [alligator, cheetah, eagle]

return true. It's basically an inventory check. I have an inventory. The customer has a list of demands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this differently. My algorithm would loop through the overall list. Since both the overall list and request list are sorted, you can loop through the overall list, while looking at the head of the request list for a match. If a match is achieved you can increment a variable representing the index for the request list, move on to the next 'request item' and compare with the next item in the overall list. Rinse and repeat...

See the code below for a further explanation:

```
public boolean checkAvailability(SortedListOfImmutables listToCheck) {
    int availableCounter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<items.length; i++){ //items is the original array
        if(listToCheck.items[availableCounter].equals(items[i])){
            if (++availableCounter == listToCheck.items.length)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Does this solve your question? Please feel free to ask questions if you don't understand anything, and let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: It does make sense. Except I just realized the availableCounter would need to equal listToCheck.items.length and not (-1) as it was in my original code. As I would need to see if there are as many animals in the inventory as there are in the listToCheck. A list of 3 animals would need to give me an availableCounter of 3.

Comment: I just wrote a few tests for it and I get an indexOutOfBoundsException when I only pass in a list of one animal.

Comment: Ahh I see. I'll edit my code real quick to solve this problem.

Comment: It looks right to me. My debugger keeps doing the "Class Not Found Exception" thing it sometimes does so I can't debug it and see what's going wrong.

Comment: The code should be complete now. What class does it say it can't find? I assumed you wrote the 'SortedListOfImmutables class'....

Comment: It just does that sometimes. Restarting eclipse generally fixes it. In the edited code, availableCounter is never being iterated is it? Wouldn't this code fail if there were 3 animals in the listToCheck for example? Because once it found the first animal, it would never check to see if the second animal exists in the inventory.

Comment: '++availableCounter' increments the value then uses it. This is the same as availableCounter = availableCounter + 1;, then using the availableCounter value. Test it and let me know if it performs properly for all inputs.

Comment: Would adding a break in the second if statement work? Once availableCounter became 1 after finding the animal in the loop. The code would see if availableCounter is equal to the length of the list (which is also 1) and if so I could just add a break there so it doesn't run the for loop again and returns true.

Comment: The break statement will exit out of the 'for (int=i...)' loop. Unless you want to do some more processing after the loop, it is better to just return true since you found out that you have the available animals in the original list. Understand?

Comment: Adding the break worked. As soon as it found the only animal that was in the list in the inventory, it exited the loop and returned true.

Comment: Glad to hear! Good luck in future programming endeavors.